# Did I not blockquote this correctly?

Tags: discussion, markdown, blockquote

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075839/cannot-find-module-in-electron/48076258#48076258), by blockquoting a blog article, and a user edited it, to remove the blockquote.

I rolled the edit back to my original revision because it didn't make sense and the user didn't leave a comment as to why he removed the blockquote.

But I'm still curious, is this not a correct approach, to quote text from an article and use the blockquote markdown to highlight that?

Comment: Seems like the right approach to me as you are quoting a block of text/code from the linked article.

Comment: You did the right thing by wrapping the answer into a quote. I don't know neither why the editor made such an edit, maybe he didn't note that you were quoting the whole answer.

Comment: That user has more than one questionable edit, the most recent one they edited a question to turn a code block into a snippet. A mod may want to go through https://stackoverflow.com/users/4540183/mr-x?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: @Stijn Probably for the `+2` reputation awarded and some gold badge. I agree that the edits are suspicious

Comment: @Adelin: Users don't get rep for edits any more beyond 2k.

Comment: @Stijn: The [block => snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48076613/revisions) edit was actively helpful, not questionable. Other than the one in the question above (which was clearly wrong, hopefully just not quite paying enough attention), what are these other "questionable" edits?

Comment: (Well, [this one is](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48075674/revisions). Intent was good, but converting JQUERY to `jquery` and GOOGLE to google doesn't actually help... :-) )

Comment: I think he aims for [Copy Editor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor). Maybe all will be clearer if after he receives the badge the edit spree abruptly comes to an end

Comment: It seems people are jumping to conclusions. The editor has explained their actions *(which has been treated quite harshly)*, didn't need the reaction they received. Let's think for a minute, at least they were willing to come to this meta post, explain their actions and face the music.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Your formatting was correct. You were quoting a article you linked, so the text should be formatted as such.

You handled correctly by rolling the edit back.